# How to effectively manage browser cache for "CMS-like" websites

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl, caching

(Sorry for the long post... trying to be as concise as I can on this.)

I am the sole volunteer developer for a free "CMS-like" website system used by over 10,000+ Toastmasters public speaking clubs around the world.  Clubs enter content and configuration settings and the system generates a free website for them using a custom template.  The system is very dynamic, so browser cache management is a key consideration.  I am continuing to struggle to come up with a robust cache management strategy that works for all my 300,000+ users for their various browsers *despite all the research I have done related to this in these forums*.  I control all aspects of the software, the Perl server code, the MySQL db, the HTML, and the javascript.  I have an htaccess set up with ExpiresByType on the server.

I am using cache buster query parameters for javascript libraries, CSS files, etc.  The Perl code patches in a RevDate query parameter into the HTML for my custom javascript files and my custom CSS:

```
<script src="/js/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js?v=9.9.3"></script>
<script src="/js/FTH/utilities.min.js?2015-06-11"></script>
// In the HTML template: <script src="/js/FTH/utilities.min.js?{{RevDate}}"></script>
```

I have the following Cache Control meta parameters set in the HTML template head section... (The template is a single HTML file w/ Mustache-style variables and section markers that allow sections to be removed by the Perl code as needed.)

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

I have recently also added the indicated lines below for outputting the HTTP headers to the Perl routine that processes the template:

```
print $COOKIE;
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
# The following have been added to the above...
print "Cache-Control: no-cache\n";
print "Pragma: no-cache\n\n";
```

(From what I am reading, it looks like having the server output the cache control headers is a better approach than using the meta tags, but not sure why.)

Despite all these approaches, I still run into cache related issues (e.g., cache not invalidated), especially with Google Chrome, if I do not also include the following forced reload script in the HTML head:

```
<script>
  {{DOCCOOKIE}}  // Set first so that a reload does not lose cookies 
   (function TriggerReload(){
     var getCookieRevDate = function(){ 
         return ((document.cookie.match(/(?:^|; )FTH2\.RevDate=([^;]*)/) || [])[1] || ''); 
     }, 
     RD = getCookieRevDate(), 
     key = "FTH2.RevDate";
     if (RD === "{{RevDate}}") { return; } // Cookie revision date matches server revision date. No reload necessary.
     document.cookie = key + "={{RevDate}}; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/"; 
     if (RD && getCookieRevDate() === "{{RevDate}}"){ location.reload(true); }  // Revision date was changed on server, and has been successfully stored locally and read back.
    }());
</script>
```

I would like to get rid of this reload script, if possible, while maintaining a robust cache management strategy.  However, to date, I have not been able to make the system properly invalidate cached JavaScript and content on a Rev Date change without the forced reload.  I end up with my Chrome users (predominantly) complaining about a number of issues and I end up having to tell them to do a manual reload. (I have a link that does a location.reload(true) as a manual fallback for their use.)

Anyone have any suggestions on how to improve on what I am doing to provide an effective cache management strategy with good performance???